# Vertically Aligning Text/Images in Tablepress (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add vertical center alignment to a table in Tablepress, but it only gives you the option to add additional CSS.

I've tried a general alignment;

```
.tablepress-id-1 td {
vertical-align: middle;
```

But it's not worked. Any help would be great. By default it appears text aligns correctly the issue are the icons I've entered into the cells.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: "By default it appears text aligns correctly...."  Do you rather mean that with the CSS snippet you tried text aligns correctly?

Comment: The Snippet hasn't actually changed anything - The text aligns the same with or without it!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [newbloggerzone.com](https://newbloggerzone.com/center-text-and-tables-tablepress/):

> Centering Text in a Specific Column in a Specific Table Only
> Here’s how to align specific columns of content in your table only:

> Go to the Plugin Options tab on the main menu of the TablePress plugin on your Dashboard.
> At the top of this page is a Frontend Options box with Custom CSS in it. This is where you need to put the code in. Make sure the “Load these Custom CSS commands to influence table styling” box is ticked.
> You then need to put specific kind of code into this box, as follows:

```
.tablepress-id-x .column-x {
text-align: center;
}
```

> where x is the number of the table and the column you want to center. All tables you create get assigned a number or ID, which is in the shortcode. This is what you put in to identify which table needs this styling, along with the columns number you want to centre.